# Occasional crash when inviting peer in multipeer connectivity

Tags: ios, multipeer-connectivity

I have a published app that uses Multipeer conncectivity to send small amounts of data at regular intervals. I am using MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser. Everything works fine when I test. However, I have been receiving crash reports from my users, not a lot, but enough to deserve my attention.

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -   [__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                       0x30b8cf03 __exceptionPreprocess + 131
1   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x3b321ce7 objc_exception_throw + 36
2   CoreFoundation                       0x30acad3f -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 532
3   CoreFoundation                       0x30acab03 +[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:forKeys:count:] + 48
4   MultipeerConnectivity                0x32420e87 -[MCNearbyServiceBrowser syncInvitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:] + 452
5   MultipeerConnectivity                0x324220cf __67-[MCNearbyServiceBrowser invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout:]_block_invoke + 84
6   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b80ad53 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b80fcbd _dispatch_queue_drain + 486
8   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b80cc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b8105f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 74
10  libdispatch.dylib                    0x3b8108dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 54
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b93bc17 _pthread_wqthread + 296
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x3b93badc start_wqthread + 6
```

Despite a lot of efforts I have been unable to recreate the crash. I have tried putting the app in the background, loosing connection, turning the network on and off etc. Usually everthing reconnects nicely, sometimes after tapping a "reconnect button", but no crashes. Does anyone have a tip about the cause or at least how to force this o happen?

The browser side looks like this:

```
-(void)setUpPP{
  self.PPid = [[MCPeerID alloc] initWithDisplayName:@"PhotoFinish"];
  self.SSid = [[MCPeerID alloc] init];

  self.PPsession = [[MCSession alloc] initWithPeer:self.PPid securityIdentity:nil encryptionPreference:MCEncryptionNone];
  self.PPsession.delegate = self;

  self.PPbrowser = [[MCNearbyServiceBrowser alloc] initWithPeer:self.PPid serviceType:@"sprinttimer" ];
  self.PPbrowser.delegate = self;
  [self.PPbrowser startBrowsingForPeers];
}

-(IBAction)startSync:(id)sender {
  [self.PPbrowser invitePeer:self.SSid toSession:self.PPsession withContext:nil timeout:10];
}

-(void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{

  NSString *displayString;
  if (state == MCSessionStateConnected && self.PPsession) {
    displayString=@"Start Sender connected";

  } else if (state == MCSessionStateNotConnected && self.PPsession) {
    displayString=@"No Start Sender in range";
    connected=NO;
  }
 [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(displaySync:) withObject:displayString waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID withDiscoveryInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
  self.SSid=peerID;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be helpful to know what action triggers `startSync:` but in `setUpPP` you are assigning a meaningless instance of `MCPeerID` (with no `displayName`) to `self.SSid` so I could see that crash happening if `startSync:` is ever called before `self.SSid` gets a real `MCPeerID` assigned to it.

My suggestion would be to start out with `self.SSid` as nil, and make sure that you are not sending invitations unless that property has a value. Going further I wouldn't rely on a single property to store an `MCPeerID` that could have it's value changed before `startSync:` is called.

Comment: Thanks for the input. You are right that it is not ideal to allocate SSid before it gets a value. I will change that. However, it seems that the problem (at least partly) was that the device connected to itself. So checking that and making sure to tear down the session when losing connection seemed to have improved things. Really frustrating not being able to recreate the crash though, I had to guess, post an update and see what crash reports are coming in.